# Creating multiple Bias-Variance Tradeoff plots in R

Tags: r, plot, model, statistics, variance

I am relatively new to R. I would like to know how to create the following graphic. I have been stuck for over two hours.

[image]

Suppose the red line - the true relationship - is y = x^2. 
Suppose I want to fit 100 linear models to 100 random samples (blue lines).

How would I do this? So far, this is what I have:

```
# create the true relationship
f <- function(x) x^2  # true model
x <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)
y <- f(x)

# plot the true function
plot(x, y, type = "l", col = "red", ylim = c(-0.2, 1.2), lwd = 4)

# fit 100 models
set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:100)
{
    errors <- rnorm(n, 0, sigma)       # random errors, have standard deviation sigma
    obs_y <- f(obs_x) + errors         # observed y = true_model + error
    model <- lm(obs_y ~ obs_x)         # fit a linear model to the observed values
    points(obs_x[i], mean(obs_y[i]), col = "green")       # mean values
    abline(model, col = "purple")    # plot the fitted model
}
```

which creates this:

[image]

in which the green dots are definitely off...
and I don't have the black dots...

Thanks!

Comment: It's better to post your code. Luckily, I had a look at before you editing it.  The green dot issue can be solved by moving `points` line out of the loop, given it is the mean linear model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your code after several adjustments:

```
f <- function(x) x^2
x <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.05)
n <- length(x)
sigma <- 0.05
y <- f(x)

plot(x, y, type = "l", col = "red", ylim = c(-0.2, 1.2), lwd = 2)

fitted <- ys <- matrix(0, ncol = n, nrow = 100)

set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:100)
{
  errors <- rnorm(n, 0, sigma)
  ys[i, ] <- obs_y <- f(x) + errors
  model <- lm(obs_y ~ x)
  fitted[i, ] <- fitted(model)
  abline(model, col = "purple", lwd = 0.1)
}

points(x = rep(x, each = 100), y = ys, cex = 0.1)
points(x = x, y = colMeans(fitted), col = 'green', cex = 0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: wow! thank you! could you explain to me what your `ys` and `fitted` matrices represent? are they y-hat values?

Comment: @sweetmusicality, indeed, every row of `fitted` contains y-hat/fitted values from each model. Then taking column averages of this matrix gives the green points. Also, every row of `ys` contains observed y in each case, which is what black points represent.

Comment: wait, so how do `fitted` and `ys` differ from ecah other?

Comment: @sweetmusicality, `ys` is what we observe (a quadratic curve with some noise) and `fitted` is the best we can to with the model (a line).

Answer (score 4):

With ggplot, e.g.

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)
y <- x^2

dat <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(1:100, function(i){
  y_err <- y + rnorm(1, 0, 0.06)
  l <- lm(y_err ~ x)$coefficients
  cbind(samp = i, intercept = l[1], slope = l[2], t(x * l[2] + l[1]), t(y_err))
})), row.names = 1:100)

ggplot() +  
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = dat$intercept, slope = dat$slope)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = rep(x, each = 100), y = unlist(dat[, 15:25])), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red", lwd = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = colMeans(dat[, 4:14])), color = "green")
```

[image]